# Restarting MySQL for every benchmark test

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, mariadb

I am performing some benchmarking tests using sysbench on my MariaDB-10.0.14 server and i was just wondering if it good practice to restart MariaDb server before performing every new test?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is.
now suppose you are running bench-marking for the very first time.
It means your MariaDB was'nt doing anything, it has just started.
now for second time if you'll run the benchmark tests on server you will not get the accurate results because the queries that are being ran by the bench-marking tool will target the databases and tables that are HOT now because of the previous test.

So, for appropriate results you should restart the server every time you run the test.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL collects statistics about the table data that is used to optimize the queries:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-index-statistics.html

To remove these statistics it is not sufficient to restart the server.  Instead, drop and recreate the complete table.  Then you do not need to restart the server.